# copying values from one nested dictionary to another nested dictionary when key pairs are the same

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have two nested dictionaries:

```
d:
{'redFish': {'redFish': 'inf', 'blueFish': 9, 'twoFish': 10, 'oneFish': 6}, 
'blueFish': {'redFish': 9, 'blueFish': 'inf', 'twoFish': 11, 'oneFish': 10}, 
'twoFish': {'redFish': 10, 'blueFish': 11, 'twoFish': 'inf', 'oneFish': 8}, 
'oneFish': {'redFish': 6, 'blueFish': 10, 'twoFish': 8, 'oneFish': 'inf'}}
```

and

```
newDict:
{'blueFish': {'blueFish': None, 'twoFish': None, ('redFish', 'oneFish'): None},
'twoFish': {'blueFish': None, 'twoFish': None, ('redFish', 'oneFish'): None},
('redFish', 'oneFish'): {'blueFish': None, 'twoFish': None, ('redFish', 'oneFish'): None}}
```

I want to transfer the values from `d` to `newDict` for pairs of keys that are the same. For these dictionaries these key pairs are

```
[blueFish][blueFish]
[blueFish][twoFish]
[twoFish][blueFish]
[twoFish][twoFish]
```

If this works then the values for these key pairs in `d` would be moved to the same key pairs in `newDict`.

I have made this piece of code to try and do this:

```
for name1 in newDict:
    for name2 in name1:
        for nameA in d:
            for nameB in d:
                if name1 == nameA and name2 == nameB:
                    newDict[name1][name2] = d[nameA][nameB]
```

However, nothing gets changed in `newDict`, as all values for all key-pairs are stil `None`. How can I fix this and why does my code not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage the fact that dictionary `keys` act like sets. You can find the keys that are common to both dictionaries with something like:

```
d.keys() & newDict.keys()
```

Which will give you a set you can iterate over:

```
{'blueFish', 'twoFish'}
```

You can do the same in the inner dicts to update just the values that are common:

```
for k in d.keys() & newDict.keys():
    newDict[k].update((k2, d[k][k2]) for k2 in newDict[k].keys() & d[k].keys())
```

I think in python 2 you can make a set directly from a dict, so this should work the same way:

```
for k in set(d) & set(newDict):
    newDict[k].update((k2, d[k][k2]) for k2 in set(newDict[k]) & set(d[k]))
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, however I get this error message: `for k in d.keys() & newDict.keys():
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'list' and 'list'`

Comment: @wilberox are you using Python 2?

Comment: Thanks @alex, I just posted and edit — I don't think you actually need the `keys()` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the intersection of the keys:

```py
set(d.keys()) & set(newDict.keys())
# {'blueFish', 'twoFish'}
```

```py
for k, v in d.iteritems():
    for i in set(newDict.get(k, {}).keys()) & set(v.keys()):
        newDict[k][i] = v[i]
print(newDict)
# {'blueFish': {'blueFish': 'inf', 'twoFish': 11, ('redFish', 'oneFish'): None}, 
#  'twoFish': {'blueFish': 11, 'twoFish': 'inf', ('redFish', 'oneFish'): None}, 
#  ('redFish', 'oneFish'): {'blueFish': None, 'twoFish': None, ('redFish', 'oneFish'): None}}
```

Comment: Thans for the suggestion. I get this error message: `    for i in newDict.get(k, {}).keys() & v.keys():
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'list' and 'list'` could this be because I am using python 2.7?

Comment: It is, you need `set(d.keys()) & set(newDict.keys())`